# How to store a number with localStorage even when the page reload

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to store a number when its value is 0

```js
var count = 3; 
var count2 = "0"; 
var count3; 
var btn = document.getElementById("btn"); 



btn.onclick = function() {

count--; 
btn.style.transform = "scale(2)";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}, 0005); 

if(count === 0) {

  /* I want to store the result here in manner that even when  the page  reload the number remains the same ( 0 in that case ) */ 
  
  var zero = localStorage.getItem(count); 
  count3 = parseInt(count2); 
 localStorage.setItem( count , count3 ); 
 
 

}


}
```

```css
#btn {

width : 300px;
height : 300px;
border : solid 2px red;
border-radius : 50%; 
transition : .1s;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

But I don't need to affect count3 to count since count is already set at 0 :( but I can't affect numbers ? I think there's only string in the 'key' for localStorage.

How I can do that ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, I think you should clarify the question. However, if the problem is that you want to assign a `number` to `count` but getting a `string` from `localStorage.getItem(count)`, you can use `parseInt` like that: `var zero =parseInt(localStorage.getItem(count))`

Comment: It works but not really the number 0 is not stored , when I reload the page I got the same problem the button is still active however its suposed to be disabled when the count is at 0. So that means the number 0 was not stored

Comment: Are you sure that there is no method that overrides this value from localstorage after refresh?
The best way to figure it out is to open DevTools from your web browser open application tab, then storage->localstorage and refresh page to see if it changes after refresh. If 'yes' then you have method that replace it after refresh.

Comment: The "count" value is set at 0 with the example below but when I reload and click on the element the value 3 takes over 0 and then I can still click on the button

Answer (score 0):

The key for localstorage is to only use String. You can define a function to parse the key to any.... When the page reload, loacalStorage can't be cleared. So you can do it like `var key = parse(localStorage.getitem(count))` in your defined function.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

> localStorage.setItem( count , count3 )

This is wrong. You should write

> localStorage.setItem( "where" , value );

So instead of setting the item in the key equal to the variable `count`, you should set the value in key `"count"`, which is a string. Otherwise, every time you change the integer `count`, you store the new value (`count3`) in a new place.

When you then reload the page, the integer `count` is then trying to fetch the stored information in key `3`.

---

Also, `count === 0` could as well be written as `count == 0` so it doesn't check if count is an integer first, and instead accepts strings (and boolean, undefined and null).

---

EDIT: added snippet as example. I refactored the code so it's more readable, commented out localStorage so you can run the snippet on Stack Overflow, and I assumed that count can't get lower than 0.

As a bonus, I removed `count2` and `count3` while changing the setTimeout from 0.005 (5ms is minimum anyway) to 50ms (half of 0.1s that is in the transition).

```js
var storedCount = getStoredCount();
const GOT_PREVIOUS_VALUE = storedCount != null;
var count = (GOT_PREVIOUS_VALUE) ? storedCount : 3;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = changeCount;

function changeCount() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    scaleButton();
    storeCount();

    console.log({count})
  }
}

function scaleButton() {
  btn.style.transform = "scale(2)";
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  }, 50);
}

function getStoredCount() {
  return localStorage.getItem('count') ;
}

function storeCount() {
  localStorage.setItem('count', count);
}
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: ok I'll try and I'll tell if it's working

Comment: It's still not working idk what's wrong with that I tried everything , I just replaced count by "count"  , I even replaced === by == I don't know how to do this. Can I get an exemple with a snippet or whatever ?

Comment: I edited the post with an example. Hope that clears things out for you.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help I actually tried this but when I reload the page I can still click on the button.   If the "count" is set at 0 I want to store it in such a way that I will not be able to click on the button anymore

Comment: Sorry. I did a mind fart. Of course it will reset to 3 if I do `storedCount != 0`. I edited and changed row 2 to just check if getItem('count') hasn't been stored before.

Comment: Im sorry to bother you again , but you sure it's working it does the same thing as before. :(

Comment: Have you a) uncommented the code, and b) put the script behind the HTML so it can find `#btn`? Alternatively for b), used `defer` on the script tag if you link it from an external file. I updated the code, and removed the part I commented out.

Comment: In the previous message i've already uncommented the code but for some reason I just restart Mamp and VS code and it works. Anyway thanks alot :)